# Record iOS device screen on mac mini using QuickTime Player (Note: My desktop doesn't have a camera)

Tags: ios, iphone, quicktime, ios8.4

I would like to make a sample video of my how my app works using quicktime player. When i open quicktime player and click **file -> new movie recording** it is not showing my device only. I am using a Mac Mini - iPhone 4s, iOS 8.4.1, is it mandatory to have camera for my desktop to successfully record the video or is there any other work around possibility?

Comment: `File- New Screen Recording` , now choose recording area, When all done click on record button.

Comment: http://etc.usf.edu/techease/4all/getting-started/creating-screen-recordings-with-quicktime-player/

Comment: I can use to this record the video from simulator. This would do for now, but is there anyway to record from device?

Comment: Are you using Yosemite on your mac? I think this only works in Yosemite.

Comment: Yes, I am using Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

you can record your iPhone screen from quick time player. No it is not mandatory to have camera for your desktop to successfully record the video.

Here are the steps to do so:

- Open QuickTime Player
- File -> New Movie Recording
- Beside record button there is a small Down arrow.
- click on that and there will be list of connected devices.
- choose the device from which you want to record the screen.
- That's it. you are ready to record your iPhone or iPad screen. click record button and start recording.

Comment: I am using macOS Sierra - I am not seeing my device show up, may you please advise, here is screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/Rwn6ipI.png

Comment: I guess the device is not properly connected. Can you make sure your device is properly connected with Lighting Cable. and it shows in iTunes.

Comment: Thank you Bhautik for trying to help, my phone had to be unlocked otherwise it wouldn't work.